# Hive SQL - values loading with quotes, remove quotes

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Trying to load a table on database and one column with string values is loading with quotes for some of the values. 
Example:

```
ac_name
"PepsiCo
"Coke
"DietCoke
```

where it should be loaded as it is in the raw CSV file which is below:

```
ac_name
PepsiCo
Coke
DietCoke
```

Why is Hive inserting quotes in front of these values? How do you remove it while loading as table?

Comment: Can you update the DDL of the table in the question along with a screenshot of some sample data? How was this csv file's data generated?
Also Try to load this data from a different file in a different table manually and see if you still see this?

Comment: It was the comma delimiter that was in quite a few values in the file while file upload which was causing character after comma in these values to truncate. Then it would populate quotes for those. I substituted comma for underscore, reloaded the file and it works. Thanks!